# Crop image when draw line with hand

Tags: ios

I have a Image view added on a view. View is using `UIBezierPath` and touch responder methods for drawing line upon dragging on screen. Now I would like to clip the part of image that are below the line. How can I achieve this.

I use below methods to draw line

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];

    [path moveToPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [path addLineToPoint:p]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please show code for cropping image?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mzcroppableview Try this URL to crop image and save to Documents directory. I hope this is useful to you.

Comment: @N J Gadhiya How to crop the image is what my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBezierPath *bezierPath;
//...

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];      
    //...

    self.bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [self.bezierPath moveToPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    //...

    [self.bezierPath addLineToPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    // Here you can call -croppedImage; method and get the image you need.
}

- (UIImage *)croppedImage
{
    [self.bezierPath closePath];

    UIImage *image = //Your initial image;

    CGSize imageSize = image.size;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);    

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    // Create the clipping path and add it
    [self.bezierPath addClip];
    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
    UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return croppedImage;
}
```

This is a fast written code, so can be possible mistakes. Sorry for that :)

Comment: Yeah, it works, I just tried it :) 
The only issue is with scale. 
So for start, choose an image with size (640,1136) and put in UIImageView.

Comment: It is not working. When I use your code I get Image like http://postimg.org/image/pwdp5mi5l/

Comment: Hmm, interesting...
Here is the test project that works for me: 
https://www.mediafire.com/?dxmq42s4iy5dy4a

Comment: Just run the project that I send you, and "draw" a shape (circle, oval, or some thing else), and see result.

Comment: You did not understand my question it seems. Upon drawing a line (Not end to end) I want only the top portion of Image alone.

Comment: Ah, now I understand.   
I think the hardest part of your question is to how to crop image to bezier path, which I showed you.  
Remains only to properly calculate the points at which you want to crop. Besides, there are a lot of cases, when it's not clear how to crop in that case. 
E.g. what result should be, if user draws line tike this:  
http://postimg.org/image/wzd83ff5z/

Comment: If user draw a line which does not create any closed path. My builder should be capable of creating the closed path. Closed Path may either arc or may touch the wall of the view.

Comment: But you didn't answer my question. 
Please, can you make a picture where you can show a result of image cropped by path that I show in previous comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57972/discussion-between-idev-and-arturdev).